# hibernate generate pojo class with field name = data base column name

Tags: java, hibernate

When I use hibernate eclipse plugin to generate java class from my table, the private field name is the same with my table name. Is there a way for me to make it to be the same with my column name instead?

For example:

```
table: User
column : name (string)
column : homeAddressId (fk to addressTable)
```

The generated class right now is:

```
User{ 
private String name;
private Address address;
}
```

I want it to be:

```
User{
private String name;
private Address homeAddress;
}
```

Is there a settings to do that?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there can be problem in the understanding between you and hibernate. Actually, what i see, there is a foreign key with other table which is `Address`, not `homeAddress`.

can you also post the other table(Address) structure.

as if the other table name is `Address` then hibernate plugin is bond to create create attribute with name `address`, as i feel plugin doesn't have intelligence of its own.

Comment: the plugin already knows my table column nam. Why can't it generate the private field in my class using that column name?

Comment: @ Sean : Your column name is homeAddressId, but it is a foreign key which have one to many associations, so it will consider the association table not the column name, rather you can see the hbm file that is being generated, you will find the key reference over there.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, your domain should be the way you want it.  If you need to make more changes to the mapping (ORM), you might need to do it in your hibernate-conf.xml.  The generated class and the current class is the same.  For example the user.xml will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class  name="User" table="ADMIN_USER_TBL">
 <id name="id" type="string" column="ADMIN_USER_ID">
        <generator class="assigned" />
 </id>
 <property name="name" column="FIRST_NAME" />
 ...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then, have the mapping for the address:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class  name="Address" table="ADDRESS_TBL">
 <id name="id" type="string" column="ADMIN_USER_ID">
        <generator class="assigned" />
 </id>
 <property name="address" column="ADDRESS1" />
 <property name="address2" column="ADDRESS2" />
 <property name="city" column="ADDRESS_CITY" />
 <property name="state" column="ADDRESS_STATE" />
 <property name="zip" column="ADDRESS_ZIP" />
 ...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Let me know if that helps! ;)

Comment: I am looking for a way to have hibernate generated class to generate the private field to be the same with the db column name. I don't want to modify both the generated class or the mapping file. Thanks for your reply but it is not what I am looking for. Am I missing something?